# call javascript function from c# page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to call a javascript function from aspx page load. But it's not working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   btn_add_more_pack.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "openform()");
}
```

The javascript :

```
function openform() 
{
   try {
       alert('enter');
   }
   catch (ex) {
   }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: I tried you same code. It is working. What is the error you get. What does your fire bug say? May be you have other error on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be `OnClick` it should be `onclick` though it doesn't matter (not case sensitive) but you can try like below.

 So on page load it should be as follows

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {    
        btn_add_more_pack.Attributes.Add("onclick", "openform()");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and tried in my system. Everything is working fine. But, one catch here:

I am using VS-2010 to work on your item.

Where have you added your javascript function? Is it inside .aspx page head section or a separate file?

If you have added the above Javascript function inside .aspx page head section, then you don't need to alter anything. Everything works fine.

But, if you have added the above Javascript function inside a separate .js file, you should remember to add reference in the .aspx head section like below

```
<script src="pathToJavascriptFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```